# Trying to use library made by Xamarin.iOS in Unity

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, xamarin

I created library using Xamarin.iOS with Visual Studio.  Both `Foundation` and `JavaScriptCore` name space are used in the library.

I'd like to use this library in Unity.
When I put this library in Assets > Plugins/iOS folder in Unity and wrote codes to call the library I made, an error occurs.
It says that there is no Xamarin.iOS.dll, so I added it and finally I could compile them.

But when I try to build it, there is another error.
Error massage is below;

```
IL2CPP error for method 'Foundation.NSObject ARKit.ARAnchor::Copy(Foundation.NSZone)' in assembly '/Users/MyName/Documents/JavaScriptRuntimeTest/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/Xamarin.iOS.dll'
Additional information: Stack empty.


IL2CPP error for method 'Foundation.NSObject ARKit.ARAnchor::Copy(Foundation.NSZone)' in assembly '/Users/MyName/Documents/JavaScriptRuntimeTest/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/Xamarin.iOS.dll'
Additional information: Stack empty.
il2cpp.exe didn't catch exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Stack empty.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1.Pop()
   at Unity.IL2CPP.StackAnalysis.StackStateBuilder.Build(IEnumerable`1 instructions)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.StackAnalysis.StackAnalysis.Analyze()
   at Unity.IL2CPP.MethodBodyWriter..ctor(IGeneratedMethodCodeWriter writer, MethodReference methodReference, TypeResolver typeResolver, IRuntimeMetadataAccess metadataAccess, VTableBuilder vTableBuilder, MethodBodyWriterDebugOptions options, ISourceAnnotationWriter sourceAnnotationWriter)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.MethodWriter.WriteMethodBody(MethodReference method, IGeneratedMethodCodeWriter methodBodyWriter, IRuntimeMetadataAccess metadataAccess, ISourceAnnotationWriter sourceAnnotationWriter, IIcallMappingService icallMapping, VTableBuilder vtableBuilder)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.CodeWriterExtensions.WriteMethodWithMetadataInitialization(IGeneratedMethodCodeWriter writer, String methodSignature, String methodFullName, Action`2 writeMethodBody, String uniqueIdentifier, MethodReference methodRef)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.MethodWriter.WriteMethodDefinition(IGeneratedMethodCodeWriter writer, MethodReference method, IMethodCollector methodCollector, IMethodVerifier methodVerifier, ISourceAnnotationWriter sourceAnnotationWriter, IIcallMappingService icallMapping, VTableBuilder vtableBuilder)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.SourceWriter.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<WriteMethodSourceFiles>b__0(IGeneratedMethodCodeWriter writer, TypeReference type)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.SourceWriter.WriteEqualSizedChunks[T](NPath outputDir, IEnumerable`1 items, String fileName, Int64 chunkSize, Action`2 writeItemAction, SourceWritingContext sourceWritingContext)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.SourceWriter.WriteMethodSourceFiles(NPath outputDirectory, SourceWritingContext sourceWritingContext, String fileName, IEnumerable`1 typeList, IMethodCollector methodCollector, Boolean writeMarshalingDefinitions)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.SourceWriter.Write(NPath outputDir, SourceWritingContext sourceWritingContext, ReadOnlyCollection`1 assemblyDefinitions, IMethodCollector methodCollector, IInteropDataCollector interopDataCollector)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.AssemblyConverter.Apply()
   at Unity.IL2CPP.AssemblyConverter.ConvertAssemblies(IEnumerable`1 assemblyDirectories, IEnumerable`1 explicitAssemblies, NPath outputDir, NPath dataFolder, NPath symbolsFolder, NPath executableAssembiesFolder, NPath monoLibFolder, NPath monoEtcFolder, NPath[] searchDirectories, String entryAssemblyName, NPath[] extraTypesFiles)
   at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args)
   at il2cpp.Program.Run(String[] args)
   at il2cpp.Program.Main(String[] args)
stderr:

Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Stack empty.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1.Pop()
   at Unity.IL2CPP.StackAnalysis.StackStateBuilder.Build(IEnumerable`1 instructions)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.StackAnalysis.StackAnalysis.Analyze()
   at Unity.IL2CPP.MethodBodyWriter..ctor(IGeneratedMethodCodeWriter writer, MethodReference methodReference, TypeResolver typeResolver, IRuntimeMetadataAccess metadataAccess, VTableBuilder vTableBuilder, MethodBodyWriterDebugOptions options, ISourceAnnotationWriter sourceAnnotationWriter)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.MethodWriter.WriteMethodBody(MethodReference method, IGeneratedMethodCodeWriter methodBodyWriter, IRuntimeMetadataAccess metadataAccess, ISourceAnnotationWriter sourceAnnotationWriter, IIcallMappingService icallMapping, VTableBuilder vtableBuilder)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.CodeWriterExtensions.WriteMethodWithMetadataInitialization(IGeneratedMethodCodeWriter writer, String methodSignature, String methodFullName, Action`2 writeMethodBody, String uniqueIdentifier, MethodReference methodRef)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.MethodWriter.WriteMethodDefinition(IGeneratedMethodCodeWriter writer, MethodReference method, IMethodCollector methodCollector, IMethodVerifier methodVerifier, ISourceAnnotationWriter sourceAnnotationWriter, IIcallMappingService icallMapping, VTableBuilder vtableBuilder)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.SourceWriter.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<WriteMethodSourceFiles>b__0(IGeneratedMethodCodeWriter writer, TypeReference type)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.SourceWriter.WriteEqualSizedChunks[T](NPath outputDir, IEnumerable`1 items, String fileName, Int64 chunkSize, Action`2 writeItemAction, SourceWritingContext sourceWritingContext)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.SourceWriter.WriteMethodSourceFiles(NPath outputDirectory, SourceWritingContext sourceWritingContext, String fileName, IEnumerable`1 typeList, IMethodCollector methodCollector, Boolean writeMarshalingDefinitions)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.SourceWriter.Write(NPath outputDir, SourceWritingContext sourceWritingContext, ReadOnlyCollection`1 assemblyDefinitions, IMethodCollector methodCollector, IInteropDataCollector interopDataCollector)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.AssemblyConverter.Apply()
   at Unity.IL2CPP.AssemblyConverter.ConvertAssemblies(IEnumerable`1 assemblyDirectories, IEnumerable`1 explicitAssemblies, NPath outputDir, NPath dataFolder, NPath symbolsFolder, NPath executableAssembiesFolder, NPath monoLibFolder, NPath monoEtcFolder, NPath[] searchDirectories, String entryAssemblyName, NPath[] extraTypesFiles)
   at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args)
   at il2cpp.Program.Run(String[] args)
   at il2cpp.Program.Main(String[] args)
   at Program.Main(String[] args)

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner:RunProgram(Program, String, String, String, CompilerOutputParserBase) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:128)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner:RunNetCoreProgram(String, String, String, CompilerOutputParserBase, Action`1) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:79)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:RunIl2CppWithArguments(List`1, Action`1, String) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:366)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:ConvertPlayerDlltoCpp(String, String, String, Boolean) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:349)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:Run() (at
```

Is it possible to use library made by Xamarin.iOS in Unity?
Thanks,

**Environment**

- Unity 2018.3.12f1
- PlayerSettings > Other Settings

  - ScriptingRuntimeVersion = .NET 4.x
  - API Level = .NET Standard 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no documentation about how to use Xamarin in Unity or use Unity in Xamarin so far. The two runtimes are not the same.

Xamarin has its own engine : [urhosharp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/graphics-games/urhosharp/index)